# Stop slide when ended

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, slider

I'm working with idangero slider and I wanna stop the slider when the second slider is reached. (slider: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php)

The user should only be able to slide once, after that the user should not be able to.
You can see a example here: [www.bvweijen.nl/23g/slider/index.php](http://www.bvweijen.nl/23g/slider/index.php)

It is a mobile slider.

I have tried this:

```
  <script>
            var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
               speed : 800,
               grabCursor: true,
               paginationClickable: true,
               onSlideChangeEnd : function() {
               if(mySwiper.activeIndex > 0){
                    mySwiper.params.noSwiping = true
                }
                //alert('OMG you touch the slide!') 
           },
        })
    </script>
```

He can find the activeIndex, but noSwiping = true doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: If you can you should create a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar so that it's easier for other people to play with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't read the API documentation correctly. In your defense it's not clear what "preventing an element from sliding" will do. Anyway here is what is states:

```
noSwiping: If true, then you can add "noSwipingClass" class to swiper's slide to prevent/disable swiping on this element.
```

That means you have to set up a class that will be the `noSwipingClass` and you have to set up `noSwiping = true` beforehand. Try something like this:

```
<script>
        var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
           noSwiping: true,
           noSwipingClass: 'do_not_swipe',
           speed : 800,
           grabCursor: true,
           paginationClickable: true,
           onSlideChangeEnd : function() {
           if(mySwiper.activeIndex > 0){
                $('.swiper-container').addClass('do_not_swipe);
            }
            //alert('OMG you touch the slide!') 
       },
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see, didn't read that! i'm trying to fix the code, but it's still not working. Is this the way how you add a class?

Comment: He added the class to the element, but it's still possible to slide. So the class is not working well. Hopes you can help me.

Comment: Does the class get added at all? Can you create a jsFiddle or something similar with your code? Also, are you using version 2.0 of the Swiper?